# How can I solve lint-gradle error in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am writing an app in android studio and when i want to sign that It says:

```
Could not find lint-gradle-27.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/27.0.0/lint-gradle- 
27.0.0.jar
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: post your build.gradle